# Are "disabilities" and "ones" grammatically correct in this context?

Tags: adjectives, relative-pronouns, modifiers

I am writing this context:

> Its Support Centre for Students with Special Needs is very appreciated since it provides **disabilities** students the same level of education as healthy **ones**.

I don't know if I used "disabilities" and "ones" correct gramatically.

Comment: In adjectival form, you could say _disabled students_. That said, I like the suggestion from @amateur – it addresses what can be a sensitive subject in a respectful manner.

Comment: I think *healthy* is **not** the antonym of *disabled*.  *Able-bodied peers* I think is probably better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my suggestion:

> Its Support Centre for Students with Special Needs is very appreciated **as** it provides **students with disabilities** the same level of education as **their peers without disabilities**.